# ant.design input group width 100% of a Col without breaking the lines

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have ant.design `Input.Group` with `Select` and `Button`.
I want to make them 100% of a `Col` (of any size).
the following code breaking the line between the `Select` and the `Button`
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bogdan-2z8ot

[image]

```
   <Row>
    <Col span={6}>
      <Form.Item label="Label">
        <InputGroup style={{ width: "100%" }} compact>
          <Select style={{ width: "100%" }} placeholder="Select a person">
            <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
            <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
          </Select>
          <Button icon="form" />
        </InputGroup>
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
  </Row>
```

I need a solution that will be suitable for any `Col` width / span.

Thanks

The link again: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-bogdan-2z8ot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how this will influence your other layout, but if you are fine with inline css then try adding **whiteSpace: 'nowrap'** in the style of your InputGroup.

```
        <InputGroup style={{ width: "100%" }} compact>
          <Select style={{ width: "calc(100% - 32px)" }} placeholder="Select a person">
            <Option value="jack">Jack</Option>
            <Option value="lucy">Lucy</Option>
            <Option value="tom">Tom</Option>
          </Select>
          <Button icon="form" />
        </InputGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. please see your answer here: https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-haze-u64by it is going out of the `Col`

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!